# Delete specific elements from a list in python 3

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a list of values for example:

```
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
```

And specific indexes like:

```
[0,3,5]
```

I want something that returns deleting the values which the index belongs to the [0,3,5] array:

```
[2,3,5,7,8,9,10]
```

Any ideas for Python 3?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `enumerate` and list comprehension.

**Ex:**

```
l = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
toDelete = [0,3,5]

print([v for i,v in enumerate(l) if i not in toDelete])
```

**Output:**

```
[2, 3, 5, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

Comment: Worked for me :)